# Database with varying numbers of entries for attributes

Tags: sql, sqlite

I try to make a database to store and query my films and sitcomes. I want to be able to query for various (pre-defined) attributes (e.g. actors, director, length).
Now, not every film has the same number of actors playing in it and I don't know how to account for this.

Let me give an example:
In the film Shutter Island are Leo DiCaprio and Mark Ruffalo playing, in Inception are Tom Hardy, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Ellen Page, Leo DiCaprio and Michael Cane playing. In Aviator is DiCaprio alone (not accurate, I know).

I could add a lot of attributes like actor1, actor2, actor3, ... But when I'm searching for films with DiCaprio, I don't know whether he's in actor1, actor2 or in which actor-attribute he's in. Still, with a query similar to `SELECT films FROM database WHERE actor = 'Leo DiCaprio'` I want to get a list with all his films in my database.

What would be the appropriate design for the database? Is this even possible with a relational database?

Thanks for your help. Maybe the awnser is obvious, but I'm a newbie to sql and databases and try to complete this for training purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where relational databases shine! A schema like below gives you flexibility in how you search and what you can return.
The important thing to notice is the one to many relationships available. A movie can have many credits, 
but a single credit must belong to a particular movie. A contributor can have many credit types and movies. They can even have many roles in a movie.

```
Contributor
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|   ContributorID     | FirstName        |  LastName        |  DisplayName     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      Leo         |  Dicaprio        |  Leo DiCaprio    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      Kate        |  Winslet         |  Kate Winslet    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |      James       |  Cameron         |  James Cameron   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|

Movie
|---------------------|------------------|
|      MovieID        |  MovieName       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |   Titanic        |    
|---------------------|------------------|

Credit
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|    CreditID         |  MovieID         |  ContributorID   |  CreditTypeID    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |     1            |  1               |    1             |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          2          |     1            |  2               |    2             |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          3          |     1            |  3               |    3             |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|

CreditType
|---------------------|------------------|
|    CreditTypeID     |  CreditTypeName  | 
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |  LeadingActor    |  
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |  LeadingActress  |  
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |  Producer        | 
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here's how you would perform your original request

```
SELECT MovieName FROM Movie m 
JOIN Credit c ON c.MovieID = m.MovieID 
JOIN Contributor co ON co.ContributorID = c.ContributorID
WHERE co.DisplayName = 'Leo DiCaprio'
```

You could also find all the credits on a movie

```
SELECT m.MovieName, c.CreditTypeName, co.DisplayName
FROM Movie m 
JOIN Credit c ON c.MovieID = m.MovieID 
JOIN Contributor co ON co.ContributorID = c.ContributorID
JOIN CreditType ct ON ct.CreditTYpeID = c.CreditTypeID
WHERE m.MovieName = 'Titanic'
```

Or every time DiCaprio was a lead LeadingActor

```
SELECT m.MovieName, c.CreditTypeName, co.DisplayName
FROM Movie m 
JOIN Credit c ON c.MovieID = m.MovieID 
JOIN Contributor co ON co.ContributorID = c.ContributorID
JOIN CreditType ct ON ct.CreditTYpeID = c.CreditTypeID
WHERE ct.CreditTypeName = 'LeadingActor'
AND co.DisplayName = 'Leo DiCaprio'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an *association* table (also called a *junction*) table with one row per movie and per actor:

```
MovieId    ActorId
```

Then you can list however many actors you want in a given movie, with each actor on a separate row.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.